# MYSQL: Easiest way to update fields between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables

in first one `(t1)` I have

```
Table [t1]
id     Product_URL
```

.

```
Table [t2]
id     Product_id    Product_URL
```

I would like to `UPDATE ALL` product_id field (from t2) to the id of the first

```
 WHERE t1.product_url = t2.product_url
```

can I do that In one query?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t2
JOIN (
    SELECT t2_2.id, t1.id as new_id
    FROM
        t2 t2_2 JOIN
        t1 ON t2_2.product_url = t1.product_url AND t2_2.product_id <> t1.id
    ORDER BY t2_2.id
    LIMIT 5000
) sub ON t2.id = sub.id
SET id = sub.new_id;
```

EDIT: [It looks like mutli-table updates do not play well with `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/10/how-to-use-order-by-and-limit-on-multi-table-updates-in-mysql/), but here's another query that accomplishes the same thing...

Comment: cool, thanx. What if there are too many rows? and I'd have to split for examples into chunks by 5000, where doI put LIMIT?

Comment: getting: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT (if I remove ORDER BY) or Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY with it

Comment: you can not apply order by in sub query